# How to install libevent on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, libevent

I'm using Ratchet on Windows Server 2012. I'd like to have Ratchet use libevent. I have completed the following two things:

1. Using MinGW, I built libevent from source and got three DLLs:

libevent-2-0-5.dll

libevent_core-2-0-5.dll

libevent_extra-2-0-5.dll

2. Installed the PECL libevent DLL in php.ini

phpinfo() does not list libevent as enabled and available. What am I to do with the three DLLs? What am I missing to get libevent up and running?